# HOw I properly install and import TensorFlow-hub without errors

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-hub

I tried to install TensorFlow-hub, but when I try to import it through the below command
**import tensorflow_hub as hub**

I face the below error.
**ImportError: cannot import name 'estimator_export' from 'tensorflow.python.util.tf_export'**

The install command for the hub is :
**pip install --upgrade tensorflow_hub**

ImportError: cannot import name 'estimator_export' from 'tensorflow.python.util.tf_export'